# Remove Accent accents from characters using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have accents in my data and want to remove from character. Example : Frédér8ic@ --> frederic
using Pyspark code

**I tried the below code:**

```
def simplify(text):
    import unicodedata
    try:
        text = unicode(text, 'utf-8')
    except NameError:
        pass
    text = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', text).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode("utf-8")
    return str(text)
```

**But getting below error**

```
text = unicode(text, 'utf-8')
TypeError: decoding str is not supported
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_trans():
    matching_string = ""
    replace_string = ""

    for i in range(ord(" "), sys.maxunicode):
        name = unicodedata.name(chr(i), "")
        if "WITH" in name:
            try:
                base = unicodedata.lookup(name.split(" WITH")[0])
                matching_string += chr(i)
                replace_string += base
            except KeyError:
                pass

    return matching_string, replace_string


def clean_text(c):
    matching_string, replace_string = make_trans()
    return translate(
        regexp_replace(c, "\p{M}", ""),
        matching_string, replace_string
    ).alias(c)
```